# How can I get real-time heart rate data in a progressive web app for phones?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm building a progressive web application (target is smart phones for now). The app needs to be able to access heart rate and heart rate variability, ideally in real-time. While it seems totally asinine, I'm open to using REST calls to some remote server if that is the only way. I'm also fine with restricting the app to only work with certain hardware if necessary. In this case, the ideal hardware would be some sort of earbud that uses optics to scan for heart rate, but at this point, I'm open...

The best that I have thought up is to find a heart rate monitor that converts the direct signal into audio and use the microphone web API. That seems like a lot more work than ideal, so I'm hoping someone has a better idea. Any ideas are welcome. Please, no one downvote anyone if it doesn't solve all my constraints. I've been working on this for a bit and I'm not sure that there is a clean and perfect solution yet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about use a Web Bluetooth that lets you control any Bluetooth Low Energy device like heart rate monitors. It will read the Service Location Characteristics (which tells your where the sensor is placed - which body part) and subscribe to notifications from the Heart Rate Characteristics, meaning you will get an event whenever the device performs a new measurement. Then use a service worker that will define the behavior of the app to mimic native app capabilities like [offline support](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/add-offline-support-to-any-web-app-c20edc4bea0e?_=nocache) and notifications.

It's like a Physical Web that you can send a link to your website from a  Bluetooth beacon to a user's device and with PWA, that link can be to your web app that looks, feels and functions like a native app. Then with Web Bluetooth, you can then speack to the device. Visit this [blog post](https://medium.com/@urish/start-building-with-web-bluetooth-and-progressive-web-apps-6534835959a6) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've come up empty with this. Do you have any example code or an link to an api for a heart rate monitor that could work? I haven't been able to find anything even remotely resembling what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If the sensor can speak Bluetooth, the Web Bluetooth API can perhaps help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for taking time to answer. Do you have any example code or an link to an api for a heart rate monitor that could work? I haven't been able to find anything even remotely resembling what I need yet.

Comment: @NickApperson were you able to make some progress on this ?

Comment: @Mic I looked through the various options that were presented and I wasn't able to get any to work at the time. I advised my partner to go a different direction over a year ago. I'm unsure of the current situation; it may have improved.

Comment: @NickApperson, thanks for the reply! iOS still not supporting it is a drag... I'll look at what Flutter can do